# Evaluate the expression $\int_1^2 \log(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4) \,dx .$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the expression
> $$\int_1^2 \log(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4) \,dx .$$

I am trying this question by writing
$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}$. Now integrating from 1 to 2 $\ln(1-x^5) - \ln(1-x)$ is undefined. So how to solve it? Also I took the help of Desmos. There also the result is showing undefined.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: But how to integrate ln(x^5 -1)?

Comment: Have you attempted integration by parts?

Comment: Play with the roots of unity to factorize and expand the logarithm before integration.

Comment: I think integration by parts will not work here in this problem because integration of 1/(x^5 -1) is undefined from 1 to 2.

Comment: It is only the question

Comment: That expression does not have a nice closed form, although one can get some kind of closed form. Using integration by parts without the algebraic reduction, $$
\int_{1}^2 \log(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)dx = [x \log(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)]^2_1 - \int_1^2 \frac{4x^4+3x^3+2x^2+x}{x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1}dx
$$
The former is easy to evaluate, and for the second term we must resort to partial fractions, which is ugly but works (you'll get an answer in terms of the fifth roots of unity).

Comment: $$I=\int ln(x^5-1)\,dx-\int ln(x-1)\,dx$$

The second integral can be evaluated by parts easily.

Let, $$J=\int ln(x^5-1)\,dx$$

Using IBP,

$$J=xln(x^5-1)-\int \frac{5x^5}{x^5-1}\,dx$$`

$$J=xln(x^5-1)-5\int \frac{x^5-1+1}{x^5-1}\,dx$$`

$$J=xln(x^5-1)-5x-5\int \frac{1}{x^5-1} \, dx$$

Now integrating $\int \frac{1}{x^5-1} \, dx$ is really tedious and messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying integration by parts with $$u = \log(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), \qquad dv = dx$$ gives a rational integral:
$$x \log(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)\vert_1^2 - \int_1^2 \frac{4 x^4 + 3 x^3 + 2 x^2 + x}{x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1} \,dx .$$

In principle we can proceed by applying polynomial long division to the new integrand and then applying the Method of Partial Fractions. In particular we can factor the quartic denominator, $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$, by observing that $(x - 1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) = x^5 - 1$, that is, that its roots are exactly the $5$th roots of unity other than $1$. So, the denominator factors as
\begin{align}x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 &= \left(x^2 - 2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{5} \cdot x+ 1\right) \left(x^2 - 2 \cos \frac{4 \pi}{5} \cdot x + 1\right) \\ &= (x^2 - \frac1\phi x + 1)(x^2 + \phi x + 1),\end{align}
where $\phi := \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{5})$ is the Golden Ratio.

Comment: It will be 4x³+3x²+2x+1.

Comment: Not 4x⁴+3x³+2x²+x.

Comment: The numerator of $u'(x)$ is $4 x^3 + \cdots$, but the new integrand is $u'(x) v(x) = u'(x) \cdot x$, which has numerator $4 x^4 + \cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$$ where
$$a=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}-i
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$
$$b=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+i
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$
$$c=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}-i
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$
$$d=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+i
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$

Expand the logarithm and use
$$\int_1^2 \log(x-k)\,dx=(k-1) \log (1-k)-(k-2) \log (2-k)-1$$

Simplify the complex numbers, recombine the arctangents and group the logarithms to get a closed form expression.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the integral
\begin{align}
I(a)=&\int\ln(1 + ax + x^2)dx\\
=& \int \ln(1 + ax + x^2)d(x+\frac a2) \\
\overset{ibp}=&\ (x+\frac a2)  \ln(1 + ax + x^2)+\sqrt{4-a^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{2x+a}{\sqrt{4-a^2}}-2x
\end{align}
to evaluate

\begin{align}
&\int\ln(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4) \,dx\\
=&\int \ln[(1+\phi x +x^2)(1-\frac1{\phi}x+x^2)]dx\\
=&\ I(\phi)+I(-\frac1{\phi})+C
\end{align}
where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$.

Answer (score 0):

By using integration by parts, which is

$$\int (uv)dx=u\int vdx-\int u'\left(\int vdx\right)dx$$

For integrating $\ln(x-1)$, consider $u=\ln(x-1)$ and $v=1$. After that its pretty easy to solve using by parts.

Now for $\ln(x^5-1)$, substitute $x^5-1=z$, so $dx=\frac{dz}{5x^4}=\frac{dz}{5(z+1)^{\frac45}}$.

So you have to solve$$\int \frac{\ln z}{5(z+1)^{\frac45}}dz$$ and by applying by parts where $u=\ln z$ and $v=5(z+1)^{-\frac45}$ where you will have to integrate a somewhat messy polynomial in the second term which can be expanded by binomial expansion and integrated(this is what first came to my mind, there are surely better ways out there).